# ORM Assign data to view

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, doctrine

Working on an MVC application with Doctrine as our ORM. Currently we're looking at improving the way we use object relations within our application, and a question came up:

> Should we directly assign a doctrine entity to the view or just an array of data?

Each has it's own advantages and disadvantages. For example, setting an entity gives our frontend devs the ability to query our database, which shouldn't be done it the view and could be used unwisely.
On the other hand, assigning an array of data means we have to first query everything they could possibly want and fetch as array. Array access also doesn't give them autocompletion.

Which do you think is our best option going forward with the least amount of potential complications?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is mostly about the efficiency/speed at which your app needs to operate. If by "frontend devs" you mean HTML/CSS devs, then they probably won't understand what kinds of queries looping the wrong thing (e.g. `$object->getRelatedObject()`) can create in the background. Something that could be performed with a single tight query returning array data may end up generating 10-15 queries that hydrate full objects and slow down the application noticeably.

If I had to generalize, I'd say that if you're building a small app where scaling up isn't a major concern, it doesn't really matter because you won't notice the speed hit and your devs have more leeway to do nasty things. Otherwise, I'd go for array data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, by "frontend devs" i meant HTML (with a lil' bit of PHP) guys. Our main concern was indeed that they could do something crazy like loop through queries or save data from the view or something; and performance is the reason we are doing the refactor in the first place. Thought it would be good to gather opinions before we went ahead with anything. Thanks.

Comment: Just to follow up; we went ahead with assigning full entities to the view to allow greater control flexibility on the front end. We plan to avoid any stupid iterations and saves through code review